# Is there a widget available that duplicates the Launcher Pro Calendar Agenda widget?

Tags: app-widgets, google-calendar

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

I want a widget that shows me an agenda of my Google calendar just like this. But I'm not using Launcher Pro anymore, I'm now on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and am using the stock ICS launcher, so I need a new widget to replace the widget from Launcher Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed - there are a few but I'd recommend Rolf's [Agenda Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.roflharrison.agenda). Lots of options and highly configurable.

Scrolling support is present, although the launcher must support scrollabel widgets like ADW / LPP / GoLauncher do.

[image: Agenda Widget screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I'm looking for. I installed it and will try it out and let you know.